# How to view two different pages of the same pdf at the same time?

Tags: pdf-viewer

I was looking forward to comparing values on different **non-consecutive** pages of the same pdf, specifically pages 3 and 11 of that pdf. I thought I could open it with another pdf viewer but I thought that maybe one pdf viewer could have that built-it function and here I am. So what pdf viewer can do that?.

I normally use **nitro pro** in windows.

[image]

Comment: Why not just make a copy then open both in the same app?

Comment: because in the app I use (nitro pro) I cannot open both documents and view them at the same time (different tabs).

Comment: Then you perhaps ought to mention that in your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Also, what platform you are on - on Mac this is trivially done by duping the file, then opening both in the built-in viewer.

Comment: you're right. I will edit my question.

Comment: Are you OK if they are in two windows (not tabs)?

Answer (score 1):

While not a dedicated PDF viewer per-se, you could achieve this with [Vivaldi web browser](https://vivaldi.com/).

It is a Chromium based web browser with many features and tools.

Using the builtin PDF viewer, you can open two different tabs with the same PDF file, each viewing independent pages.

Vivaldi can [tile tabs for viewing pages side by side](https://help.vivaldi.com/desktop/tabs/tab-tiling/), using that feature you can tile two or more tabs displaying the same or different PDF files in arbitrary pages.