# A PDF viewer that can save and reopen tabs at the exact page one last stopped at

Tags: pdf, macos, pdf-viewer, ebooks

I often read PDF ebooks and open multiple pages on different tabs of the same book. e.g. With book X, I open pg 2 on tab 1, pg 20 on tab 2, pg 30 on tab 3 etc. I currently use Chrome to do this. But if I restart Chrome, or if I save the session and reopen the session tabs, the tabs dun show me the pages where I last left off, ie all tabs get reset to pg 1.

Is there an app that can save the exact page where I last left off on each tab, and supports opening the same document over multiple tabs?

It should be able to also do things like those mentioned in the question of:
[How to view two different pages of the same pdf at the same time?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/83033/how-to-view-two-different-pages-of-the-same-pdf-at-the-same-time)
[PDF reader that can save multiple sessions?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/40446/pdf-reader-that-can-save-multiple-sessions)

Requirements:

- MacOS 10.13.6
- Open source if possible

Comment: On Windows, [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader) has what you need. Could you check if it's possible to run it over Wine on Mac?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [zotero](https://www.zotero.org/).

It has an amazing pdf reader where you can open the same pdf in multiple tabs, and it'll reopen to whatever position it was closed at. You have amazing options to annotate and sync your annotations too. I personally use this and found it to be an amazing solution to manage pdfs.

Another amazing option is [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/en-gb/).

Comment: Okular doesn't seem to be available for macOS.